# Secure my code?

Tags: javascript, security, licensing

I'm starting a website and want to keep my product from being stolen.

I'm spent much time and energy creating a js heavy site.

Now I realize that there's no way for me to make it impossible to steal. My question is, what licenses should I put in my code, also what are the legal ramifications of someone using my code without permission?

Also is minification enough, or do I need something more? I want to make it easier for someone to just write a new implementation of my site rather than reusing my code.

What are some other steps I can take to keep my site in demand and not have someone else use my code on their site?

As this will be my main source of income I would like to protect as such.

Comment: http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx is a basic way to help. But in the end anyone dedicated can reverse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't spent too much time in obfuscating your code. It's not worth it, because JS is client side so it's public.

Everything you make is copyrighted by default. Just spent your time making the best website ever and make sure you stay the best website ever.

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly copyright your code.  You do this by adding the text

```
Copyright (C) 2012 [your name or business name]. All rights reserved.*
```

in each of your source files.  Then, you don't worry about it, because you probably won't find out if someone copies you anyway.  But if they do, they've broken copyright law, and you would call a lawyer.

There are ways to further obfuscate your code, but they are all futile because they are all reversible.  They have to be, else the browser couldn't run them.

*The text "All rights reserved" is not required, but it is often used to add emphasis.

http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ1.pdf page 4 bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

You are unlikely to prevent people using your code.

Obfuscating will make it hard for amateurs to understand and modify your code.

Copyrighting will make professionals less likely to use it without permission.

The chances are that unless you're doing something really groundbreaking, your code doesn't have a lot of scrap value, so people aren't going to steal it (certainly not in an obvious way).

However, if you are absolutely set on protecting the intricate parts of your code, build an API on your server to do that work, instead of the Javascript.